# Change attribute of img when scroller for value data-small

Tags: jquery

Need to change the **SRC** of the image when the scroll goes down.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/tsiftgN.png" data-small="http://i.imgur.com/q4j8B5W.png">
```

must have the value of **data-small** when the scroll is down but if the scroll back to top return the original value **SRC**.

jquery

```
num = $('.navbar').offset().top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar').height(50);

    } else {
        $('.navbar').height(80);

    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ovq0u0L5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update the image src attribute like so:

```
$('img').attr('src', $('img').attr('data-small'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgajera/ovq0u0L5/3/

Answer (score 0):

The code in this fiddle handles your approach by adding data-big with the original source to your image as well. 
Simply save the original and the small src to variables and swap them with `.attr("src")`

```
num = $('.navbar').offset().top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var big_src = $('#myimg').data("big");
    var small_src = $('#myimg').data("small");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar').height(50);
        $('#myimg').attr("src",small_src);

    } else {
        $('.navbar').height(80);
        $('#myimg').attr("src",big_src);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovq0u0L5/1/